# cocos2d-x 3.1 serialize int to string map

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I store leader board data (Name-score mapping) in a std::multimap. Now I need to serialize it in a file and deserialize to show the player. How to do that using cocos2d-x 3.1? Is there a way or I should use Boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default way for serializing objects, instead you can create a `Dictionary` and set all keys by converting them to string and write it as `plist` file. You can check [FileUtilsTest](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/tree/v3/tests/cpp-tests/Classes/FileUtilsTest) for more details of reading and writing game data.